Can I use pod readiness as rate limit?
So, my service is a long run api service.
Each container can only servce 4 request at the same time.
If the 5th request comes in, the service may starts to response very slow.
So I want to use a proxy service behind my api in the same pod.
If there are 4 requests are working, the prxoy may turn readiness off.
Which should cause LB keep this pod away from new request?
Is that a good idea ?
Some design advice is fine.
Update 1:
Yes I tried some of gateway and LB and they don't work.
Because the api gateway can't distinguish those pods, it usually send more requests to some pod and cause slow response.
Even there are other pods can serve one more request(in normal status).
Update 2:
I accept @mohammed-ehab's suggestion as an answer.
Although the sidecar solution needs more management efford and experiments.
It still the best action I can take for my issue.

one simple approach to go with it to use side-care container as reverse-proxy, configure the readiness to be to this proxy and make the incoming requests is only sent to the another container as long as the requests being processed is less than the required numbers

Is a rewrite of the application logic a possibility? Requests are placed in a queue system (rabbit?) and the application only takes it when it can?

@MohammedEhab It sounds a solid idea! I would try it in recent. Could be a candidate answer.

@DawidKruk Very smart! I acutally devide the application into to 2 parts.
The offline part is already use the queue solution you metioned.
But I still need to deal with a realtime response api, and the application logic is doing its best. From the buiness view.

You can use pod readiness to influence traffic flow, it's not designed for rate limiting and could introduce problems in your system. Using an API gateway, service mesh, or application-level rate limiting is more reliable and scalable approach

It is a fair idea, but not works.
Because the api gateway can't distinguish those pods, it usually send more requests to some pod and cause slow response.
Even there are other pods can serve one more request(in normal status).

The sidecar proxy idea is viable but involves a trade-off in terms of complexity and management overhead. A simpler and more scalable approach might involve using HPA with request queueing or leveraging a circuit breaker pattern in a service mesh. However, if you need the granular control provided by the sidecar approach, it could still be the best solution, especially if you can manage the added complexity.
